# Are Prevarieties irreducible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

In Goertz-Wedhorn, a prevariety is defined to be a *connected* space with functions that locally is an affine variety (were an affine variety is a space with functions that is isomorphic to the space with functions of an irreducible algebraic set. The functions of an irreducible algebraic set are just the regular functions). As being irreducible is stronger than being connected, one would expect that there are non-irreducible prevarieties. So the question is:

Are there non-irreducible prevarieties?

I think the answer should be no: Every prevariety is homeomorphic to $X(k)$, where $X$ is an integral scheme of finite type over $k$ (see p. $80$ or so in Goertz-Wedhorn, were they prove that there is a category equivalence between prevarieties and integral schemes of finite type.). But then $X$ is irreducible and so also $X(k)$, as $X(k)$ is very dense. The details of the last step are the following:
Assume we have open sets $U, V \subseteq X$ such that $U \cap X(k) \neq \emptyset \neq V \cap X(k)$. We have to prove that the intersection is nonempty. We have

$$(U \cap X(k)) \cap (V \cap X(k)) = (U \cap V) \cap X(k).$$

As $U \neq \emptyset \neq V$ and as $X$ is irreducible, we have $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$. But as the map $W \mapsto W \cap X(k)$ is a *bijection* from the topology of $X$ to that of $X(k)$ (Here we use that $X(k)$ is very dense) it follows that $(U \cap V) \cap X(k) \neq \emptyset$, thus $X(k)$ is irreducible.

So, if my argument works, I ask you: Why are prevarieties not defined to be irreducible? And can one show directly by the definition of a prevariety that it is irreducible?

Comment: Isn't the union of two intersecting lines connected but not irreducible?

Comment: What is your argument that it is connected?

Comment: And one also has to ask how this is a prevariety. I think the two lines are no open subsets of this union, so it would be difficult to find an affine cover.

Comment: I see, their definition is that it's locally isomorphic to an irreducible algebraic set. That changes things.

Comment: I think what you want to do is this: argue that if there is more than one irreducible component then two of the irreducible components have to meet (use connectedness). Then the member of your cover containing the meeting point won't be an irreducible affine algebraic set. This disallows stuff like $(xy = 0) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$. We can't go back in time but it would be good to explain their definitions a bit more in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the question and made a bit clearer what a prevariety is. I also expanded the argument that every prevariety is irreducible.